# Em unit in CSS doesn't change font-size value as expected, why?

Tags: css

When the screen size is 1365px and less I set `body {font-size: 85.333333331%;}` so that the header, main, footer elements have 16px font-size. When you open a browser's developer tools you see that the `header` and `div.container` nested inside the `header` really have 16px font-size ... so far so good. `h1#logo` nested inside the `div.container` has a `font-size: 0.48em` declaration. However, when I check the computed tab in google chrome I see that the actual font-size is 9px, but 16px * 0.48 = 7.68px, so why am I getting a different value there? This error breaks my entire header which leads to the elements not being properly vertically aligned. Thanks for your help.

```css
/* general */
body {
 margin: 0;
 font: 100% "Open Sans", sans-serif;
 color: #7f7e7d;
}

header, main, footer {
 font-size: 1.171875em; /* 18.75px / 16px */ 
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, p, blockquote, figure, ol, ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main {
 display: block;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 3.3333333333em; /* 62.5px / 18.75px */
 font-weight: 400;
}

h3 {
 font-size: 1.5557333333em; /* 29.17px / 18.75px */
 margin: 1.1733333333em 0; /* 22px / 18.75px */
 font-weight: 400;
}

p {
 font-weight: 300;
}

a {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 0;
}

.container {
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
 list-style: none;
}

.menu > li {
 float: left;
}

.hide {
 display: none;
}

.cf:before, .cf:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
}
.cf:after {
 clear: both;
}

/* header */
header {
 background: #000;
 color: #ccc;
 font-weight: 300;
}

header .container {
 position: relative; /* kvoli jazykovemu menu, ktore bude absolute */
 z-index: 1;
}

/* logo */
#logo {
 float: left;
 font-size: 0.48em; /* 9px / 18.75px */
 font-weight: inherit;
}

#logo a {
 display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.logoPic {
 display: inline-block;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 background: url(../img/logo/logo.png) no-repeat left center;
 width: 148px; /* logo width */
 line-height: 7.6666666666666666666666666666667em; /* 69px / 9px */
 padding-right: 18px; /* priestor pre lomitko */
 position: relative;
}

.logoPic::after {
 content: "/";
 position: absolute;
 text-indent: 0;
 right: 3px;
 font-size: 40px; /* logo zostane stale rovnako velke, preto fixna velkost pre lomitko */
 color: #ffcc00;
}

/* navigation */
nav {
 float: right;
}

nav a {
 display: block;
}

#nav > li > a {
 line-height: 3.68em; /* 69px / 18.75px */
}

#nav > li {
 position: relative;
 margin-right: 1.2266666666666666666666666666667em; /* 23px / 18.75px */
}

#nav > li:last-child {
 margin-right: 0;
}

#nav > li:hover:not(.sub) > a {
 color: #bf9900;
}

#nav > li.sub:hover > a::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 60%;
 margin-left: 20%;
 margin-right: 20%;
 height: 0.26666666666666666666666666666667em; /* 5px / 18.75px */
 background: #ffcc00;
}

#nav > li.sub:hover .submenu {
 visibility: visible;
}

/* navigation submenu */
.submenu {
 position: absolute;
 top: 3.7866666666666666666666666666667em; /* 71px / 18.75px */
 left: -1.0666666666666666666666666666667em; /* 20px / 18.75px */
 background: #000;
 list-style-type: none;
 visibility: hidden;
 transition: visibility .15s;
}

.submenu a {
 padding: 0.55626666666666666666666666666667em 0.67866666666666666666666666666667em; /* 10.43px / 18.75px | 12.725px / 18.75px */
}

.submenu li:hover {
 color: #bf9900;
}

/* languages */
#languages {
 position: absolute;
 right: -9.2266666667em; /* 173px / 18.75px */
}

#languages a {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 3.68em; /* 69px / 18.75px */
}

#languages li::after {
 content: "/";
 padding: 0 0.16em; /* 3px / 18.75px */
}

#languages li:last-child::after {
 content: "";
 padding-right: 0;
}

#languages li:hover a {
 color: #bf9900;
}

/* media queries */
@media (max-width: 1365px) {
 body {
  font-size: 85.333333331%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="container cf">
   <h1 id="logo">
    <a href="#">
     <span class="logoPic">Marek Petrik</span>Professional Photographer
    </a>
   </h1>

   <nav>
    <ul id="nav" class="menu cf">
     <li><a href="#aboutMe">O mne</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Služby</a></li>
     <li class="sub"><a href="#">Portfólio</a>
      <ul class="submenu ">
       <li><a href="#">Svadba</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Modeling</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Príležitostné</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Architektúra</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Príroda</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Deti</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Referencie</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Cenník</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

   <ul id="languages" class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">SK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DE</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: `<nav>` and `ul#languages` elements are important too. They scale down to 58px height, but the `h1#logo` stays 69px high as if there was no media query with the `body {font-size: 85.333333331%;}` declaration. You need them as a comparison.

Comment: Actually, you are only _assuming_ that the font-size will be 16px by default, but that is not guaranteed at all. Try setting the root unit in `html` to make sure that the font-size is actually defined as 16px. Also, keep in mind that people can enlarge the text on your page and you are relying on _very specific_ sizes here. These specifics can even change when a slight change is made in text rendering.

Comment: That's true, but if the font-size changes from 16px to a different value em units take that into account. I set the font-size to 100% so I am not taking away privileges from users. I want them to be able to set whatever font-size they want in their browser and so everything scales accordingly. The thing I want to know is why the `<nav>` and `ul#languages` elements scale down to 58px height, but the `h1#logo` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

em value will be related to it's immediate container otherwise known as the parent. I think you'll probably want to use rem which is always related to the font-size of the `<html>` or what's called the document root.

In this Snippet, the em are rem. There's two buttons +/- which will modify the font-size of document root.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('#in1, #in2').on('click', function(e) {
  var cur = $('#hook').css('font-size');
  var res;
  var mod = $(this).data('v');
  
  res = parseFloat(cur) + parseFloat(mod);
  $('#out1').val(res);

  $('#hook').css('font-size', res);
});
```

```css
/* general */

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: 100%"Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #7f7e7d;
}
header,
main,
footer {
  font-size: 1.171875rem;
  /* 18.75px / 16px */
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
blockquote,
figure,
ol,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
main {
  display: block;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.3333333333rem;
  /* 62.5px / 18.75px */
  font-weight: 400;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.5557333333rem;
  /* 29.17px / 18.75px */
  margin: 1.1733333333rem 0;
  /* 22px / 18.75px */
  font-weight: 400;
}
p {
  font-weight: 300;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu > li {
  float: left;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
/* header */

header {
  background: #000;
  color: #ccc;
  font-weight: 300;
}
header .container {
  position: relative;
  /* kvoli jazykovemu menu, ktore bude absolute */
  z-index: 1;
}
/* logo */

#logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 0.48rem;
  /* 9px / 18.75px */
  font-weight: inherit;
}
#logo a {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.logoPic {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png) left center no-repeat contain;
  width: 148px;
  /* logo width */
  line-height: 7.6666666666666666666666666666667rem;
  /* 69px / 9px */
  padding-right: 18px;
  /* priestor pre lomitko */
  position: relative;
}
.logoPic::after {
  content: "/";
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: 0;
  right: 3px;
  font-size: 40px;
  /* logo zostane stale rovnako velke, preto fixna velkost pre lomitko */
  color: #ffcc00;
}
/* navigation */

nav {
  float: right;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
}
#nav > li > a {
  line-height: 3.68rem;
  /* 69px / 18.75px */
}
#nav > li {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1.2266666666666666666666666666667rem;
  /* 23px / 18.75px */
}
#nav > li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
#nav > li:hover:not(.sub) > a {
  color: #bf9900;
}
#nav > li.sub:hover > a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  height: 0.26666666666666666666666666666667rem;
  /* 5px / 18.75px */
  background: #ffcc00;
}
#nav > li.sub:hover .submenu {
  visibility: visible;
}
/* navigation submenu */

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.7866666666666666666666666666667rem;
  /* 71px / 18.75px */
  left: -1.0666666666666666666666666666667rem;
  /* 20px / 18.75px */
  background: #000;
  list-style-type: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility .15s;
}
.submenu a {
  padding: 0.55626666666666666666666666666667rem 0.67866666666666666666666666666667rem;
  /* 10.43px / 18.75px | 12.725px / 18.75px */
}
.submenu li:hover {
  color: #bf9900;
}
/* languages */

#languages {
  position: absolute;
  right: -9.2266666667rem;
  /* 173px / 18.75px */
}
#languages a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 3.68rem;
  /* 69px / 18.75px */
}
#languages li::after {
  content: "/";
  padding: 0 0.16rem;
  /* 3px / 18.75px */
}
#languages li:last-child::after {
  content: "";
  padding-right: 0;
}
#languages li:hover a {
  color: #bf9900;
}
/* media queries */

@media (max-width: 1365px) {
  body {
    font-size: 85.333333331%;
  }
}
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  max-width: 35ex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 80;
}
#in1,
#in2,
#out1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  max-width: 3.5ex;
}
#in2 {
  left: 10.5ex;
}
#out1 {
  left: 3ex;
  z-index:11111;
  font-size:18px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
#out1::after { content:'px' }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id='hook'>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id='fixed'>
    <button id='in1' data-v='1'>+</button>
    <output id='out1'></output>
    <button id='in2' data-v='-1'>-</button>
  </header>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <header>
    <div class="container cf">
      <h1 id="logo">
    <a href="#">
     <span class="logoPic">Marek Petrik</span>Professional Photographer
    </a>
   </h1>

      <nav>
        <ul id="nav" class="menu cf">
          <li><a href="#aboutMe">O mne</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Služby</a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub"><a href="#">Portfólio</a>
            <ul class="submenu ">
              <li><a href="#">Svadba</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Modeling</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Príležitostné</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Architektúra</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Príroda</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Deti</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Referencie</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Cenník</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <ul id="languages" class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">SK</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">EN</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">DE</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but if the width of the viewport is 1365px and less, the `header` and `div.container` elements have 16px font-size. The `h1#logo` element has 0.48em font-size and its parent is `div.container` element. So, why this `h1#element` doesn't have 0.48*16px=7.68px font-size, but instead it has 9px font-size. Why is it?

Comment: The parent of `#logo` (i.e.`.container.cf`)..also `#logo` is set to `font-size:inherit` *and* also it will base it's ems references to `.container.cf`, whitch is 1.171875em. When you use ems, that is the problem. You can't base calculations based on one measurement, that's what rem does. If you bothered to look at my Snippet, you'll see that it is 7.68px.

Comment: I did and it works very well, thank you for that. However, can you clarify why em units don't work in this case? I don't understand why it results to 9px when the font-size of `#logo` is set to 0.48em and its parent font-size is 16px for viewport width 1365px and less.

Comment: It works, that's great! `#logo`'s ***parent's*** font-size is `1.171875em` and that is based on the font-size of `#logo`'s grandma's font-size and if the grandma's font-size happens to be in ems, *then* it'll go on on and on until either an ancestor has a measurement ***not*** set in ems or until document root (which is `<html>` and in web API `documentElement`. ) So you see how using ems becomes a confusing mess of unmanageable references of inaccuracies? Your logical and ordered way of measurement can only be realized in rem not the chaotic em. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use vw(viewport width) it resizes the font according to window size.

```
  h1 {
      font-size: 5.9vw;
    }
    h2 {
      font-size: 3.0vh;
    }
    p {
      font-size: 2vmin;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dolphine/uj50trfn/

Comment: True but this disregards the fact that `em` units are useful for allowing text-sizing relative to one font unit. Suggesting using `rem` and settings `html { font-size: 16px; }` might be more useful. You would also need some query selectors to not get a fontsize of .001px on very small sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but that's not the answer to why the exapmle above doesn't work.